# How to create class with constructor which allow to create some object based on existing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, constructor

```
class Point3D:
    def __init__(self, x=10, y=2, z=5):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


# ---------------------------------------------

pt = Point3D(4, 2)

print(pt.__dict__)
```

do I understand correctly that an existing object with local variables is already registered in the POINT3D class, and can it be argued that in this case the creation of a new object of the POINT3D class will be based on the **INIT** function already registered?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. There is not _constructur_ in Python, just the `__init__` function. What do you mean by "object with local variables"? Are you referring to the default values for the arguments? Please try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

According to your constructor, if you do not give any parameter while creating an object say like,

```
`pt = Point3D()`
```

by default, the values of 10,2,5 will be assigned to x,y,z.
now let's say,

```
pt = Point3D(4,2)
```

then a point3D object with 4,2,5 assigned to x,y,z will be created

Comment: when we explicitly create a new object 
'pt = Point3D (4,2)'
Does this mean that it was created on the basis of another, already existing?

Comment: no, in any function, if we give parameters in this form def __init__(self, x=10, y=2, z=5):, it takes the values to the parameter as default values. it is not created on the basis of another, but its created with default options then and there

Comment: is it possible to make an object based on the previous one already created?